# Books on shelf problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Rashida keeps her collection of 162 books on 3 shelves.

There are 42 books on the first shelf, $x$ books on the second shelf, and the number of books on the third shelf is 2 times the number of books on the second shelf.

What is the value of $x$, the number of books on the second shelf?

Comment: What have you tried? Could you change the title so that the title is the question you are asking?

Comment: As @jMdA said, please show what you've tried so far.

Comment: i have the answer, thanks anyways?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Total books $= 162$
books on 1st shelf $= 42$
books on 2nd shelf $= x$
then books on 3rd shelf $= 2x$
Thus $42 + x + 2x= 162$
thus $3x = 120$
implying $x = 40$
Total books on 2nd shelf $= 40$

Comment: thank you so much

Comment: @TimerahGolden You can mark the answer right if you find this answer acceptable

Comment: do you know how to solve for triangles?

Comment: @TimerahGolden What do you mean by "solving for traingles"? Do you have a specific question in mind?

Comment: well nvm i passed that assignment, but do you know how to solve for the geometric mean?

Comment: between 4 and 6

Comment: @TimerahGolden geometric mean is a function of 2 numbers. What do you mean by how to solve for geometric mean between 4 and 6? Do you want to calculate geometric mean for 4 and 6?

Comment: its okay i figured it out thanks

Answer (score 0):

Easy, so we can know how much the number of books combined from the second and third shelf is $162 - 42 = 120$. The number of books on the third shelf is 2 times the number of books on the second shelf so there are 3 units of the second shelf, which basically means there are 3 times the number of books on the second shelf and the third shelf than is the number of books on the second shelf shelf. So basically $$x = \frac{120}{3} = 40$$

:)

Comment: thank you for everything :)

Comment: @TimerahGolden Do you understand what I explained? Is it okay?

Comment: If you have any questions please don't hesitate to ask

Comment: yes, i divided by 2 because it said "2 times" instead of 3. im just not good with any word problems yk

Comment: do you know how to solve for triangles by any chance?

Comment: @TimerahGolden You can accept an answer if it's correct, click on the tick besides the answer, you can also accept the other person's because their's is the same please tick both

Comment: Yes, I do know to solve for some triangles, like pythagoras @TimerahGolden

Comment: do you have a snap or messenger or anything i can send you a picture to?

Comment: Please ask another question and I can help you @TimerahGolden there is an option to add pictures

Comment: i do not see the option. would i have to see it by posting another question?

Comment: Yes, that is how you do it =) @TimerahGolden Notify me when you posted it so I know when to help you

Comment: okay just a second

Comment: okay i did something but idk if i did it right because im on a computer and i dont really know how to work it but its posted

Comment: @TimerahGolden Can you provide me a link to it? Because I don't really see it

Comment: okay i dont know how and it wont let me paste a picture so its okay

Comment: but i do thank you for the help